# Activity that Open Camera Laggy Start

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-camera

I have an Activity that displays a Camera Preview. And it is laggy when it is launch.

About 2 seconds delay and when the Activity comes up. It feels laggy.

I have seen other apps that opens a Camera Activity but they open really smoothly.

Any ideas what can I do to improve the activity opening performance?

Thank you

EDIT: I am testing on a device. Other apps like instagram also runs on the device. When opening the Instagram camera. It opens really smoothly.

Comment: it is laggy on the emulator. have you tried in actual device?

Comment: @helldawg13 on device